# What is equivalent in Flutter for JSON parsing?

Tags: json, flutter

Is there any G-SON/Jackson/Mos-hi/ equivalent in Flutter?

Comment: What's your use-case, you can use `jsonDecode`/ `jsonEncode`

Answer (score 1):

use json of the dart:convert package. Here is an example :

```
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

main() {
  final json = '{"a": "b"}';
  final decoded = JSON.jsonDecode(json);
}
```

Check out the official doc [here](https://dart.dev/guides/json#parsing-json).

In my latest project I use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) it works well for me

Answer (score 1):

In Dart you do not have to import packages like Jackson, Gson. Just use `json.encode()` to encode and `json.decode()` to decode. Or as others mentioned use `jsonDecode` / `jsonEncode`. All of the available through Dart's `import 'dart:convert'`.

Ex:

```
import 'dart:convert';
//....
String str = "{'name': 'Asanka'}"l

try {
  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(str);
  print(map["name"]);

  String backToStr = json.encode(map);
  print(backToStr);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```